# Array of 10 pointer to char[2][2] array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For a pointer to an `[2][2]` char array, I can write: `char (*p)[2][2]` and
for an array of 10 elements of type pointer to char: `char* p[10]`.

How do you write an array of 10 elements of type pointer to `char[2][2]`?

Why does this statement have a syntax error?

```
char (*)[2][2] p[10];
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`.

Comment: sorry guys for my bad speaking

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is usually better to use `std::` containers, especially for simple tasks, where fighting with plain arrays (or even worse: pointers) can be a pain. But not always, not everywhere. `vector` is not a solution for every problem.

Comment: i am writing a game(tetris) for commodore 64 with a C cross compiler which doesn't support class.

Comment: @MasoudFard Then you should tag your question as C, not C++.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan pointers belong to both C and C++, I don't think we should tag with C++ only the subset of C++ that's not a part of C.

Comment: thank you all for help, i edit tags.

Comment: @vsoftco Agreed, but the op states he is using a C compiler. It can prevent people from proposing solutions or alternatives unavailable to him.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use

```
char (*p[10])[2][2];
```

But you should really use a `typedef`, as these decl. can become exceedingly complicated:

```
typedef char (*ptr_arr)[2][2]; // our pointer-to-char[2][2]
ptr_arr p[10]; // now we have a clean syntax, this is an array of pointers to char[2][2]
```

You can also use the new `using` in C++11 like

```
using ptr_arr = char(*)[2][2];
ptr_arr p[10];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should just use a `typedef`:

```
typedef char array[2][2];
typedef array *ptr_to_array[10];

ptr_to_array x; // an array of 10 elements of type pointer to char[2][2]
```

That way you won't stump all future readers of your code and make them stare at it for a few minutes.

Or, with C++11:

```
using ptr_to_array = std::array<
                         std::array<std::array<char, 2>, 2>*,
                         10>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't a requirement that the items are allocated in adjacent memory, then one sound alternative is to put all manners of complex type declarations inside structures:

```
typedef struct
{
  char array[2][2];
} my_type;

my_type* ptr_array[10];
```

This have the advantage of not hiding pointers behind typedefs, which is questionable practice in some cases. Particularly when mixing pointers and arrays, since arrays will decay into a pointer to the first element whenever used in an expression.

(If items must be allocated adjacently, then you can still use this method, but you need to kill struct padding with some non-standard mechanism such as `#pragma pack(1)`)

Comment: Regarding the array decay, you'll end up with:  "Ah yes, here is my pointer to the first element of the array of ten array pointers to 2x2 arrays. Trivial."  :)